# google app script trying to access post data on web app via do post

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script

[image: this is the out put of(e.parameters)]

I need to access formIDArray but in appscript return nothing when i call that. And how can i access this object ("FormIDArray[]") from the appscript

Comment: Please add codes that you have already try

Comment: function doPost(e) {
  var array = e.parameters;
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(array.FormIDArray))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

Comment: according to google doc they said , e.parameters returns array for ever key. but i coudn't access to that key because it is already array, i think it was iside a array within array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array = e.parameters["FormIDArray[]"];
```

e.parameters convert every key's to have an array. there for array containing keywords become ("array[]") appending "[]" that thing end of keyword. You can access that by simply as describe top. :)